# Firebase authWithOAuthPopup minimises the browser window after successful login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am using Angular + Firebase to build my application.
I have integrated Google Sign In using

```
auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google",{scope:'email',remember:'sessionOnly'}).then(function(authData) {
//Some code
 $location.path = url;
}
```

This login works fine on one system.
But on some other system for every browser below problem is taking place:

1. After login popup appears
2. Then after successful login browser window gets minimised in system tray.

Is there any way to bring control to the parent window after successful login without getting window minimised.

Also I have added window.location instead of $location.path in the login code to resolve the issue but no luck:

```
auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google",{scope:'email',remember:'sessionOnly'})
   .then(function(authData) {
      window.location = url;
   }
```

I have checked browser settings as well. Popups are also allowed. But still same thing happening.